# Estimating intercept term in simulation study

Tags: r, regression, simulation, intercept

I am working on a simulation study in which I have generated data to mimic a scenario with treated and untreated members of a population along with a number of baseline covariates. I am using those covariates in a logistic regression model to determine treatment status, but need to set an intercept term for that model to induce a set, desired treatment prevalence in my study population. Through researching the best way to do this, it seems as though other simulation studies have used a bisection approach (or possibly a grid search) to achieve the same ends, but I am unclear on how to implement those methods for this purpose. I've been beating my head against this for days, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Reference](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.6276/pdf) In the bottom of this paper, he reads in a value which he claims would be derived from a bisection approach, but does not detail how. This is what I am attempting to replicate.